# FolderBrowserDialog displaying the error "The Folder xxxx can't be used. Please choose another folder."

Tags: c#, windows

I am developing a windows desktop application. One of its features make it necessary to access folders on the phone connected to computer. But when I am selecting the folder on my phone using FolderBrowsreDialog it is displaying this error. 
"The Folder xxxx can't be used. Please choose another folder."

My OS is windows 8 and my phones OS is android 4.4. I'd like to know why I am receiving this message and what is the correct way to access folders on my phone using C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the phone connected to your PC using the UMS or MTP protocols?

UMS is [USB Mass Storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_mass_storage_device_class), a communication protocol used by many USB storage devices like external hard drives, flash drives, and some phones, MP3 players and cameras. It effectively exposes the device's storage as a standard storage device that is given a drive letter (on Windows) and acts almost entirely like a local storage device.

MTP, or [Media Transfer Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol), is a more limited protocol, mostly supported by some phones, cameras and MP3 players/media devices. It allows access to a more restricted subset of data on the external storage device, and is exposed as a special device in Windows, not as a drive letter. This is often the case when a device has only one storage device (without external SD card), when part of it is reserved for the system and part available as a virtual SD card for user apps.

MTP devices are not standard filesystems, and so many systems that are designed to work with them - such as the FolderBrowserDialog - will fail. You can see that many shell extensions are also missing when you right-click a folder or file. This is because they, too, rely on the standard filesystem APIs, which are unavailable for MTP.

You can tell if your phone is connected as UMS or MTP by looking at its icon in the My Computer explorer window - if it has a Phone icon, it's probably MTP. If it shows up as an External Drive with a drive letter, it's probably UMS. The phone itself will usually say it too - my Nexus 5 (with Android 4.4) says "Connected as Media Device" in the notification tray.